# Django model CharField throws int() error when calling save()

Tags: django, django-models

Here's my model:

```
class MarketData(models.Model):
    data_source = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And here's the code that I keep testing

```
python3 manage.py shell
```

Then, I run this

```
from q.models import MarketData
data = MarketData("Broker")
data.save()
```

Which throws the error

> File
>   "/home/soverton/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py",
>   line 946, in get_prep_value
>       return int(value) **ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Broker'**

I've run the following and get status ok messages

```
python3 ./manage.py makemigrations q

Migrations for 'q':
  q/migrations/0006_auto_20170110_1911.py:
    - Alter field data_source on marketdata
```

And finally, I push those with migrate.

```
python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, q, sessions
    Running migrations:
      Applying q.0006_auto_20170110_1911... OK
```

So what am I getting an int() error when saving when it should be saving a char?

I recently reformatted the project to switch from SQLite to PostgresSQL and deleted migration history. Is there something weird going on with the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41463473/django-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't directly attributing the field names to the arguments.

The correct answer is

```
data = MarketData(data_source="Broker")
data.save()
```

Comment: And the reason is that there is a hidden field `id`, which stores integer primary keys.